# OEM adapter will only charge if the battery is first disconnected from the logic board before it's plugged in

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging, power

I'm trying to get to the bottom of this weird issue I seem to be having. I have a OEM charger that wouldn't seem be charge my Macbook pro 13 retina (late 2012), model a1425. I recently did a battery replacement and read somewhere that if you disconnect the battery from the logic board first it might work.

Sure enough, when I disconnect the battery and plug the adapter in, the light on the OEM adapter turns on, then reconnect the connect the battery to the logic board, restart and everything works fine. Battery is connected, OEM is charging it.

The problem is once i unplug the adapter, it wont charge again. I'll plug it back in and no light comes on.

I've experimented where I'll have it plugged in, no light on and as soon as I start unscrewing the battery from the logic board, it'll come on.

Does this mean that the battery is causing an issue? I've recently been advised that it could also be the DC in board since a 3rd party adapter charges it without a problem but want to avoid replacing the DC in board if that's not the issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: I think you have it reversed. The computer operates and charges correctly with the 3d party charger, which indicates the battery and DC-in board are OK. What's left is the OEM charger, which I suspect is faulty. You could confirm by borrowing another OEM charger, and trying it.

Comment: This is now the third one I've tried. I've ordered an 85w and a 60w to try both, returned those then ended up ordering another one to try when I made the decision to try and change the dc-in board